# Get response headers from Ruby HTTP request

Tags: ruby, httprequest

I'm making an HTTP request with Ruby using Net::HTTP, and I can't figure out how to get all the response headers.

I tried `response.header` and `response.headers` and nothing is working.

Comment: Net/HTTP has a notoriously bad API. If you were using another one, such as httpclient, `response.header` would have just worked.

Comment: What do you mean by bad? Why do I want to avoid it?

Comment: The library itself isn't bad, but the API is clunky and unintuitive as you have discovered. I always use httpclient or a wrapper library with more features like HTTParty, Rest-Client, etc. when I can.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Definitely something to consider for the future! Thanks again.

Comment: Net::HTTP is a fairly low-level library, so you have to write a bit more code to accomplish the same thing you can do with other libraries, however, at the same time, it also gives you access to things you can't do in other libraries. Its API isn't bad, nor is it clunky, it's just low level.

Comment: @theTinMan we can agree to disagree on that one. Lots of Rubyists dislike Net::HTTP's interface. Also, what can you do with it that you cannot with httpclient?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The response object actually contains the headers.

See "[Net::HTTPResponse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3//libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html)" for more infomation.

You can do:

```
response['Cache-Control']
```

You can also call `each_header` or `each` on the response object to iterate through the headers.

If you really want the headers outside of the response object, call `response.to_hash`

Answer (score 19):

The response `Net::HTTPResponse` contains headers from `Net::HTTPHeader` which you can get from `each_header` method as said by @Intrepidd which will return an enumerator as below:

```
response.each_header

#<Enumerator: #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>:each_header>
[
  ["x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN"],
  ["x-xss-protection", "1; mode=block"],
  ["x-content-type-options", "nosniff"],
  ["content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"],
  ["etag", "W/\"51a4b917285f7e77dcc1a68693fcee95\""],
  ["cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"],
  ["x-request-id", "59943e47-5828-457d-a6da-dbac37a20729"],
  ["x-runtime", "0.162359"],
  ["connection", "close"],
  ["transfer-encoding", "chunked"]
]
```

You can get the actual hash using `to_h` method as below:

```
response.each_header.to_h

{
  "x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", 
  "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block", 
  "x-content-type-options"=>"nosniff", 
  "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", 
  "etag"=>"W/\"51a4b917285f7e77dcc1a68693fcee95\"", 
  "cache-control"=>"max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", 
  "x-request-id"=>"59943e47-5828-457d-a6da-dbac37a20729", 
  "x-runtime"=>"0.162359", 
  "connection"=>"close", 
  "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that the [`RestClient`](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) library has the expected behaviour for `response.headers`.

```
response.headers
{
                          :server => "nginx/1.4.7",
                            :date => "Sat, 08 Nov 2014 19:44:58 GMT",
                    :content_type => "application/json",
                  :content_length => "303",
                      :connection => "keep-alive",
             :content_disposition => "inline",
     :access_control_allow_origin => "*",
          :access_control_max_age => "600",
    :access_control_allow_methods => "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    :access_control_allow_headers => "Content-Type, x-requested-with"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need **user friendly** output then `each_capitalized` can be used:

```
response.each_capitalized { |key, value| puts " - #{key}: #{value}" }
```

This will print:

```
 - Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 - Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 - Connection: keep-alive
 - Status: 401 Unauthorized
 - Cache-Control: no-cache
 - Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2018 09:06:39 GMT
```

Comment: This should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is also easily achieved with [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) as an alternative:

```
HTTParty.get(uri).headers
```

Answer (score -1):

To store it in a hash =>

```
response_headers = {}
your_object.response.each { |key, value|  response_headers.merge!(key.to_s => value.to_s) }

puts response_headers
```